# How to fix count() when linking multiple tables together

Tags: sql, ssms

Im removing an attribute I have called B_Price_per_hour since it should've been derived in the first place but it messed up one of my codes so I had to recreate it and I couldn't quite get it right.

```
SELECT c.Customer_ID, SUM(hours_of_use * C_price_per_hour) AS Total_Sales, COUNT(b.Booking_ID) AS Total_Visits
FROM CafeCustomers c, Booking b, Computer AS cc, BookingToComputer AS bc
WHERE c.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID AND b.Booking_ID = bc.Booking_ID AND cc.Computer_ID = bc.Computer_ID 
GROUP BY c.Customer_ID
ORDER BY SUM(hours_of_use * C_Price_per_hour) DESC;


SELECT c.Customer_ID, SUM(hours_of_use * B_Price_per_hour) AS Total_Sales, COUNT(Booking_ID) AS Total_Visits
FROM CafeCustomers c, Booking b
WHERE c.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID
GROUP BY c.Customer_ID
ORDER BY SUM(hours_of_use * B_Price_per_hour) DESC;
```

The query that includes BookingToComputer and Computer shows the incorrect result of the count() function.

Results of the first query:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsJ8N.jpg

Results of the second (desired results) query:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EHig.jpg

Created this as well and still has the same problem:

```
SELECT cc.Customer_ID, SUM(hours_of_use * C_price_per_hour) AS Total_Sales, COUNT(b.Booking_ID) AS Total_Visits
FROM CafeCustomers AS cc
INNER JOIN Booking AS b ON b.Customer_ID = cc.Customer_ID 
INNER JOIN BookingToComputer AS bc ON bc.Booking_ID = b.Booking_ID 
INNER JOIN Computer AS c ON c.Computer_ID = bc.Computer_ID 
GROUP BY cc.Customer_ID;
```

---

Table Info:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booking](
    [Booking_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [B_price_per_hour] [int] NOT NULL, (Removing this one)
    [Customer_ID] [int] NOT NULL, )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookingToComputer](
    [Booking_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Computer_ID] [int] NOT NULL, )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CafeCustomers](
    [Customer_ID] [int] NOT NULL,)



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Computer](
    [Computer_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [C_price_per_hour] [int] NOT NULL,)

INSERT INTO Booking VALUES (1, 14, 1)
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES (2, 5, 1)
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES (3, 12, 2)
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES (4,7,3)
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES (5, 12, 2)
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES (6, 7, 5)
INSERT INTO Computer VALUES (1, 7)
INSERT INTO Computer VALUES (2, 7)
INSERT INTO Computer VALUES (3, 7)
INSERT INTO Computer VALUES (4, 7)
INSERT INTO Computer VALUES (5, 7)
INSERT INTO Computer VALUES (6, 7)
INSERT INTO Computer VALUES (7, 5)
INSERT INTO Computer VALUES (8, 5)
INSERT INTO BookingToComputer VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO BookingToComputer VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO BookingToComputer VALUES (2,5)
INSERT INTO BookingToComputer VALUES (3,3)
INSERT INTO BookingToComputer VALUES (3,8)
INSERT INTO BookingToComputer VALUES (4,7)
INSERT INTO BookingToComputer VALUES (5,6)
INSERT INTO BookingToComputer VALUES (6,4)
INSERT INTO CafeCustomers VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO CafeCustomers VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO CafeCustomers VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO CafeCustomers VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO CafeCustomers VALUES (5)
```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ive edited in an inner join statement assuming thats what you were referring to. It still has the same problem though

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add: The `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables. Sample data for the tables as `INSERT INTO` statements, **not** images. The expected result with the given sample data as text **not** images. Tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: @stickybit ive added what you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was playing around and figured out I had to add DISTINCT to the count